# Copy wildcard filenames from main bundle to Documents?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I can copy files from my main bundle to my Documents directory by filename with the code below, but how can I copy based on wildcard?  For example I have several files named myimageX.jpg (x representing a random number).  I would like to loop through all of them that are contained in my main bundle and if they don't exist in Documents, copy them.

```
BOOL success;
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

myfileName = @"myimage322.jpg";
documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
filePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:myfileName];

success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath];
if(success) return;
NSString *filePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:myfileName];
[fileManager copyItemAtPath:filePathFromApp toPath:filePath error:nil];

[fileManager release];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method fileExistsAtPath would be helpful. First enumerate through the contents of the bundle and check whether the same file (of the same filename) exists in the Documents.

Here is how to do it:

```
NSString *docsDir = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
NSString *bundleDir = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];

NSFileManager *localFileManager=[[NSFileManager alloc] init];
NSDirectoryEnumerator *dirEnum = [localFileManager enumeratorAtPath:bundleDir];

NSString *file;

while (file = [dirEnum nextObject]) {

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:file]]) {

        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:[bundleDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:file] 
                                                toPath:[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:file] error:nil];         
    }

}

[localFileManager release];
```

This is a modified version of the code from NSFileManager class reference that can be found here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: This is great but there are tons of files in this bundle and I would hate to have the loop through all of them very often.  Is there a way to loop through files only contained within a specific group that was created in Xcode?

Comment: You can enumerate through the contents of the specified folder. Create a folder and add it with "Create folder references for any added folders" checked. Then, you should be able to loop through the contents of that folder - not the entire resources folder.